# How can I get my react app to compile in localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I purchased a template online. I tried to customize it, when I use the command yarn start on my terminal I got a message said " failed to compile". The project is a React app.
Can anyone help me plz...

Here's my github link below.
https://github.com/josmorea/my-clairr-app.git
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lkA8.png)

Comment: Please include the error in the question description instead of in a photo. This will help those answering see the error and those searching for the same error find this question.

Answer (score 2):

try to run "yarn" or "npm install" before run "yarn start".
If this does't solve try "yarn add bootstrap".

I think you are not downloading 'node_module' before starting the project.
The folder contains all the necessary dependencies for your project to run. Using the command "yarn" or "npm install" you would be downloading this folder in the project.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it. But I guess answer is more complete than yours.

Answer (score 1):

Your project required `bootstrap` and error clearly shows that

run `npm install bootstrap --save` or `yarn add bootstrap`

**EDIT 1**

`npm install @fullcalendar/bootstrap --save`

Comment: Thank you @Nisharg Shah! I used the command yarn add bootstrap. And then It showed a different error. Failed to compile.

./src/pages/Calendar/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@fullcalendar/bootstrap' in '/Users/moreaufilms/Dropbox/my-clairr-app/src/pages/Calendar'

Comment: I run yarn add bootstrap in the terminal it's successfully installed. After that I also run npm install @fullcalendar/boostrap --save.

Comment: I got this message in the terminal.

Comment: josmorea@MacBook-Pro-2 my-clairr-app % npm install @fullcalendar/bootstrap --save
npm install @fullcalendar/bootstrap --save
npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty.
npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/moreaufilms/.npm/_logs/2020-12-23T23_14_41_417Z-debug.log
josmorea@MacBook-Pro-2 my-clairr-app %

Comment: install the dependency on your root of the project folder